# SSH from different countries with openvpn configured on pfsense and dd-wrt?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, openvpn

I have vpn set up in two different countries A (primary, where I live) and B (secondary, which I visit once or twice a year) and would like to SSH to my devices across the vpn.

**My Setup:
Country A:**

adsl2 modem in bridge mode > Dedicated Pfsense box (acting as dhcp server and firewall and has openvpn configured from purevpn) ASUS Wireless router in AP mode Gigabit switch rest of the network which consists of various devices including a Pi running Tor relay and a wireless camera.

**Country B:**

Adsl 2 modem not in bridge mode Linksys e1200 AP (flashed with dd-wrt and configured with openvpn using my purevpn account) Pi running tor relay and IP cam connected via wifi. I Also have a wireless range extender just in case.

**What I already know:**

My VPN provider needs to give me a dedicated IP which I will get shortly before I travel to country B in a month.

**What I'm confused about:**

Will I need to forward relevant ports on firewalls on both sides for each client/machine individually?

**What I need to know:**

Is this set up possible? I SSH into my clients regularly over LAN but it would be sweet if I could check out how my relays and cameras are doing from another country. 2.The setup in country A is working and tested but I won't be visiting country B till next month. Am I using the right configurations for Country B with respect to hardware and general setup? I can't test it untill I get there and I won't be able to buy additional parts when I am there.

**P.S** More info: I have static WAN IPs provided by the ISP in both countries. I am using the **VPN for privacy** even though they will give me a dedicated IP It will be somewhere in between A and B and physically quite far from me.I plan to run exit relays on my raspberry pis.